# if parent have no element then unbind click event

Tags: jquery

this is my xml file:-

```
<root>
<child1 entity_id = "1" value= "Asia">
    <child2 entity_id = "2" value = "india">
        <child3 entity_id = "3" value = "Gujarat">
            <child5 entity_id = "5" value ="Rajkot"></child5>
        </child3>
        <child4 entity_id = "4" value = "Rajshthan">
            <child6 entity_id = "6" value = "Ajmer"></child6>
        </child4>
    </child2>
</child1>
</root>
```

here is my code:-

```
<script>
data = false;


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li").live("click", function(event) {
    /*if (event.target.id === '9426') {
        //$(this).unbind('click');
        alert('this is last !!')
        */
    $("li").hide();
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        loadChild($(this).attr("id"), event);
        return false;
    })
});

function loadChild(id) {
    var obj = $("#" + id);

    if(obj.data("loaded") == null) {
        ul = "<d>";
        var path = (id == 0) ? "root" : "[entity_id='" + id + "']";
        $(data).find(path).children().each(function(){
             var value_text = $(this).attr('value');
             var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
             ul += "<li id='" + id + "'>" + value_text + "</li>";
         });
         ul += "</d>";

         $("#" + id).before(ul);
         obj.data("loaded", true);
    } else {
        $("#" + id + " ul").remove();
        obj.data("loaded", null);
    }
}

 $(function() {
     $('#1').click(function() {
     $(this).hide();
      $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "final.xml",
             dataType: "xml",
             success: function(xml) {
                data = xml;
                loadChild("0");
                $(xml).find('child1').each(function(){
                var value_text = $(this).attr('value');
                var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
                $("<li id='" + id + "'></li>")
                             .html(value_text)
                             .appendTo('#firstLevelChild');
                             $(this).unbind('click');

        });       //close each(      
    }
         }); //close $.ajax(
     }); //close click(
 }); //close $(
</script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p>
       <div id="1">
         <span  id='update-target'>Click here to load value</span>
         <ol id="0"></ol>
       </div>
    <div id="firstLevelChild">
        <ol id="0"></ol>
        </div>
        </p>
</body>
</html>
```

with this code i am click on any value its soud be hide..
but if the last child have no sub child then its not hide 
means no click event work on last child...
thanks all to help me...

Comment: Where's your code?  Makes no sense as is.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle and we resume from that code :)

Comment: i am add my code please cheak...

Comment: Add your HTML code too...

Comment: What does `loadChild` do?

Comment: @fedmich sorry i dont know how to add on jsfiddle but wait a mnt i am adding my totaly code here :)

Comment: Hey Jack, welcome to SO. go to this page http://jsfiddle.net/ we need your HTML code as well

Comment: @fedmich i am add my all code here please check it... and help me better... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ohihef/2)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul").live("click", function(event) {
    if($(this).children().size() > 1){
      $(this).find('li').first().hide();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
      loadChild($(this).attr("id"), event);
      return false;
    }    
 });
});

<ul>
   <li>Asia</li>
   <ul>
       <li>India</li>
       <ul>
          <li>Gujarat</li>
            <ul><li>Ahmedabad</li></ul>
       </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Pragnesh, the inside UL should be inside the li item

Comment: This won't work in OP's case as the data is not in the HTML, but in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Saw your code now...

First some tip,
At the current state it is now, it's a bit hard to read the code.

Maybe you can consider **re-writing** it? Remember write less, do more.

re-write and answer the question:

```
What should your code be doing?
```

Comment: Hey nnnnn, I think it could be an answer for him. if he gets confused, maybe he needs to re-write it? sometimes it helps.

Comment: @fedmich thanks to help me better its solve thanks for give the time :)

Comment: +1 for you Jack, keep on learning :) jquery has more tricks for you to use :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length` to get the number of children for a node.

I have cleaned up your code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="loader">
        <span id='update-target'>Click here to load value</span>
    </div>

    <div id="firstLevelChild"></div>

    <div id="path"></div>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
data = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "./final.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                data = xml;
                ul = $("<ul></ul>");
                $(xml).find('child1').each(function(){
                    var value_text = $(this).attr('value');
                    var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
                    li = $("<li id='" + id + "'></li>");
                    li.html(value_text);

                    ul.append(li);
                    $(this).unbind('click');

                });       //close each(      
                ul.appendTo('#firstLevelChild');
            }
        }); //close $.ajax(
    }); //close click(

    $(document).on("click", "li", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        loadChild($(this).attr("id"), event);
        return false;
    });
});

function loadChild(id) {
    var obj = $("#firstLevelChild #" + id);

    if(obj.data("loaded") == null) {
        ul = "<ul>";
        var path = (id == 0) ? "root" : "[entity_id='" + id + "']";

        // Only if it contains children
        if( $(data).find(path).children().length > 0) {
            $("li").hide();
            $("#path").text($("#path").text() + " - " + obj.text());
        }

        $(data).find(path).children().each(function(){
            var value_text = $(this).attr('value');
            var id = $(this).attr('entity_id');
            ul += "<li id='" + id + "'>" + value_text + "</li>";
        });

        ul += "</ul>";

        obj.after(ul);
        obj.data("loaded", true);
    } else {
        $("#" + id + " ul").remove();
        obj.data("loaded", null);
    }
}
```

**Output** (After two clicks)

```
<div id="firstLevelChild">
    <ul>
        <li id="1" style="display: none;">Asia</li>
        <ul>
            <li id="2" style="display: none;">india</li>
            <ul>
                <li id="3">Gujarat</li>
                <li id="4">Rajshthan</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="path"> - Asia - india</div>
```

Comment: if i click on Asia then Asia Is hide but how can possible display asia in new div... when i click on any text its hide but display any other div like a path... where you click its display...

Comment: @JackPhp Can you be more specific? You want to display `Asia` after hiding it?

Comment: yes after click Asia Asia hide in div one and display on another div its call something like path

Comment: now i am click on path value like Gujarat than display there child list agian means click event work in path...

Comment: @JackPhp Please put your solution as part of your question, not in my answer.

Comment: Do you need any more help?

Comment: yes i need but wait i ask new question :) thanks for all dear thumps up  for you

Comment: check if you are free:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660621/if-click-on-path-value-then-its-display-there-child-in-the-div